# Order of Map.Entry<String, Object> of map in getJdbcTemplate().queryForList in return type List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

Are the Map.Entry are in the order of sql I wrote? Below is my sql:

```
String sql= "select a.assetgroup, a.assettype, a.description as assetgroupdesc, a.icontype from asset a";
List<Map<String, Object>> data= getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);
```

Comment: Does queryForList return Map?

Comment: no list of Map i.e., List<Map<String, Object>>

Comment: Map.Entry cannot guarantee the order or creation.